# Difference between database and server

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

So I know the main differences (correct me if I'm wrong) but a database is a place where data is stored and a server is where a database and other stuff is stored so it can receive requests for the data it stores and send this data to computers and other servers.

However this has become very blurred for me when deploying my Django app to heroku and using AWS S3 for media files. When I upload a media file from my Django app, I'm not sure what's being sent to heroku or AWS, I'm not even sure what's meant to be sent each. And where are the databases? (Or where should they be?)

With all the above known then, how would one get a file/data from wherever the file/data is stored into a view so it can be displayed if it's a media file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

server is any physical / virtual machine (in network) where you can store files, run apps. database is application running on server which holds the data. AWS s3 is just like a server but you cant run apps on s3 but you can use it just for storage purpose. (you can say this is hard disk in cloud)

Now how you are storing files through your app is the question? 
but for sure s3 should contain actual file and app (actually linked database) should contain the url for the media file. (if you need to access this file in future)

Answer (score 0):

In the most cases media files (like profile pictures) are not stored in databases. They are just stored in the storage system of the server. This storage could also be hosted by any kind of storage service (e.g. Amazon AWS S3).

In common, you only store data in a 'real' database (mysql, nosql, ...). This data is for example the user profile information. These databases you might hold on Heroku.

Files like music, photos and documents are often not stored in a database but stored as they are on the harddisk. (sometimes compressed)